# FireStorePagingAdapter not receiving realtime updates

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am testing `FirestorePagingAdapter` from https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/version-3.4.0-dev

The problem is, **I'm not receiving update / change / delete events** (when items do change). What can I be missing that everything works perfect, but I just don't receive the realtime events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior.

The `FirestorePagingAdapter` in the FirebaseUI library is designed to **get** data, not to listen for realtime updates.