# The new paging library can also work with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, android-architecture-components

The new [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) can also work with Firebase real-time database or Cloud Firestore? I know that it works asynchronously but is there any way it can work with a real-time database?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article, [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Firestore, you can use [`FirestorePagingAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorepagingadapter):

> The `FirestorePagingAdapter` binds a Query to a `RecyclerView` by loading documents in pages. This results in a time and memory efficient binding.
>
> The FirestorePagingAdapter is built on top of the [Android Paging Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we are using `FirestorePagingAdapter` we lose the real-time feature, is it correct?

Comment: @IoanaP. Peter is right, you can paginate using `FirestorePagingAdapter` and you're also right guessing that you'll lose the real-time feature. Please see Frank's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273741/firestorepagingadapter-not-receiving-realtime-updates) where he explains that `FirestorePagingAdapter` is designed to get data, not to listen for realtime updates.

Comment: @IoanaP. If you want to use the real-time feature you should use [FirestoreRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#choosing-an-adapter), binds a Query to a RecyclerView and responds to all real-time events included items being added, removed, moved, or changed. Best used with small result sets since all results are loaded at once. If you have large result sets, you can load data in small chunks and for that I recommend you see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)**.

Comment: Thanks Peter, thanks Alex! `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is what I was looking for.