# How to use pagination button with FirestorePagingAdapter from Firebase UI?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I followed the FirebaseUI doc about [firestorepaging adapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#using-the-firestorepagingadapter), but now I intend to to reload "next page" using a button?

Can somebody give guidance how to proceed from here?

```
Query baseQuery = mItemsCollection.orderBy("value", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

// This configuration comes from the Paging Support Library
// https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Config.html
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(10)
        .setPageSize(20)
        .build();

// The options for the adapter combine the paging configuration with query information
// and application-specific options for lifecycle, etc.
FirestorePagingOptions<Item> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Item>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(baseQuery, config, Item.class)
        .build();
```

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592325/is-there-a-way-to-paginate-queries-by-combining-query-cursors-using-firestorerec/50692959)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method on button click using an `ArrayAdapter`. If you intend to use `FirestorePagingAdapter` you'll lose the real-time feature as Frank explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273741/firestorepagingadapter-not-receiving-realtime-updates).

Comment: Reworded to make question more clear

Comment: @AlexMamo I prefer firestorepaging adapter because I don't need real-time features in my app

Comment: The paging adapter is designed for infinite scrolling, so you shouldn't have to add a button—it'll just keep loading forever as you scroll.