# FIrestorePagingAdapter - update item data on click

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-paging, android-paging-library

I am using FirestorePagingAdapter to load data from firestore and display them in recyclerView.
I get the item and bind it to the view.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, model: Question) {
        holder.bind(model)
    }

fun bind(question: Question) {
  //here I load questionData in my viewholder
}
```

I set onClickListener to textViews in my viewHolder, my question model has up to 5 options which are shown in my viewHolder, so when user presses one I want to update data to the model

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val pressedQuestion = getItem(adapterPosition)?.toObject(Question::class.java)
           }
```

Inside clickListener I get pressed question by calling getItem and toObject.
There I want to update field `pressedQuestion.questionId = "answered"`
But when this view is scrolled of the screen and than back on sreen data doesn't seem to be changed, questionId field remains the same even though I set it to "answered".
I tried calling every version of notifyDatasetChanged method but it doesn't work. 
How can I change data that FirestorePagingAdapter is loading in my viewHolder from inside onClickListener

Comment: So you want to get realtime updates when you do some changes?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273741/firestorepagingadapter-not-receiving-realtime-updates) out.

Comment: I don;t want to get realtime updates from firestore, because when user selects one option I don't want to write to firestore, instead just change one field in that object that was binded.

Comment: hi Alen, did you get a solution for this?