# Adapter for Firebase collection with realtime insert with pagination

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I need a suggestion for Adapter with Firebase real time insert on collection.  `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` loads all document if not limit is not set. I have seen some [example](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firestore-pagination-with-real-time-updates-ce05a87bb902) for paging data with updating query but they have done it without `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. [Officials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) also suggest to reuse and update `Query` range for pagination.

Anyway i can use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` with updating query for pagination.
Does `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` support updating query? I think not.

Then should i use just simple `RecyclerView.Adapter` like given example ?

Comment: Actually, I wrote that article, and yes, you can use the solution written there or you can use [FirestorePagingAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorepagingadapter) to achieve pagination but unfortunately without real-time updates.

Comment: @AlexMamo so i can't update the query that passed in `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`? . And thanks for that article its really helpful

Comment: The `FirestorePagingAdapter` is apart of the `Firebase-UI` library and as Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273741/firestorepagingadapter-not-receiving-realtime-updates): *The FirestorePagingAdapter in the FirebaseUI library is designed to get data, not to listen for realtime updates.*.